# Como realizar select dinamico con Jquery sin base de datos

Tags: jquery, funciones, formularios, select

Hola tengo un form con varios select que se activan dependiendo de lo que vaya seleccionando el cliente. Ya logré que los primeros dos select oculten y muestren los datos, pero me hace falta activar otros 8 select.A este momento si el cliente selecciona "Pre-Diseñado" se oculta el resto de las opciones, si selecciona "Perfil-Propio" despliega el siguiente select "Cantidad de Pruebas". Pero es en este punto que tengo el problema, necesito que si el cliente elige "1 Prueba" solamente me muestre 1 select (Test 1). Si el cliente elige "2 Pruebas" se muestren 2 select (Test 1 y Test 2) y así sucesivamente.

Aquí el HTML

```js
function seleccionado(){
    var opt = $('#data1').val();
    
   // alert(opt);
    if(opt=="Perfil-Propio"){
        $('#cp').show(500);
        
    }else{
        if(opt=="Pre-Diseñado"){
            $('#cp').hide();
            $('#data2').hide(500);
            $('#data3').hide(500);
            $('#data4').hide(500);
            $('#data5').hide(500);
            $('#data6').hide(500);
            $('#data7').hide(500);
            $('#data8').hide(500);
            $('#data9').hide(500);
        }
    }
}

function seleccionado2(){
    var opt = $('#data1').val();
    var opt2 = $('cp').val();
    
   // alert(opt);
    if(opt=="Perfil-Propio"){
        $('#data2').show(500);
        
    }else{
        if(opt=="Pre-Diseñado"){
            $('#data2').hide(500);
        
            }
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="data1" >Elección de las pruebas</label>
        <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data1" name="data1" onchange="seleccionado()"required>
          <option selected value="Pre-Diseñado">Pre-diseñado por expertos</option>
          <option value="Perfil-Propio">Perfil-Propio</option>
        </select>
      </div><br>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="cp" id="cp" onchange="seleccionado2()" style="display:none;">
        <label for="cp" >Cantidad de Pruebas</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" name="cp">
            <option value="9p">Elije la cantidad</option>
            <option value="1p">1 Prueba</option>            
            <option value="2p">2 Pruebas</option> 
            <option value="3p">3 Pruebas</option>
        <option value="4p">4 Pruebas</option>
        <option value="5p">5 Pruebas</option>
        <option value="6p">6 Pruebas</option>
        <option value="7p">7 Pruebas</option>
        <option value="8p">8 Pruebas</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div><br>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data2" id="data2" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data2" >Test 1</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data2" name="data2">
            <option value="test.1.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test.1.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data3" id="data3" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data3" >Test 2</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data3" name="data3">
            <option value="test.2.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test2.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data4" id="data4" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data4" >Test 3</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data4" name="data4">
            <option value="test.3.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test.3.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
       </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data5" id="data5" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data5" >Test 4</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data5" name="data5">
            <option value="test.4.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test.4.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data6" id="data6" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data6" >Test 5</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data6" name="data6">
            <option value="test.5.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test.5.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
       </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data7" id="data7" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data7" >Test 6</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data7" name="data7">
            <option value="test.6.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test.6.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data8" id="data8" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data8" >Test 7</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data8" name="data8">
            <option value="test.7.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test.7.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
       </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data9" id="data9" style="display:none;">
        <label for="data9" >Test 8</label>
       <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data9" name="data9">
            <option value="test.8.1">Evin-1</option> 
            <option value="test 8.2">Evin-2</option> 
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues primero que nada y nomas como comentario, en el html tienes ids repetidos, es decir, tienes una div con id="data1" y un select con id="data1" lo cual en teoría no deberia de hacer, porque te va a causar conflictos si haces un selector con esos ids. esto se repite con todos varios div y select

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" name="cp" id="cp" onchange="seleccionado2()" style="display:none;">
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" name="cp">
```

Pero bueno, regresando al tema yo lo que haría seria poner un identificador relacionado con el valor del selector que ocupas, como tus selectores son del 1 al 8 yo puse un data-number a cada div que deseo ocultar/mostrar con ese valor pero solo el numero

```
<div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="data1" >Elección de las pruebas</label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data1" name="data1" onchange="seleccionado()"required>
              <option selected value="Pre-Diseñado">Pre-diseñado por expertos</option>
              <option value="Perfil-Propio">Perfil-Propio</option>
            </select>
          </div><br>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="cp" id="cp" onchange="seleccionado2()" style="display:none;">
            <label for="cp" >Cantidad de Pruebas</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" name="cp">
                <option value="9p">Elije la cantidad</option>
                <option value="1p">1 Prueba</option>            
                <option value="2p">2 Pruebas</option> 
                <option value="3p">3 Pruebas</option>
                <option value="4p">4 Pruebas</option>
                <option value="5p">5 Pruebas</option>
                <option value="6p">6 Pruebas</option>
                <option value="7p">7 Pruebas</option>
                <option value="8p">8 Pruebas</option>
            </select>
          </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data2" id="data2" data-number="1" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data2" >Test 1</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data2" name="data2">
                <option value="test.1.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test.1.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data3" id="data3" data-number="2" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data3" >Test 2</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data3" name="data3">
                <option value="test.2.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test2.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data4" id="data4" data-number="3" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data4" >Test 3</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data4" name="data4">
                <option value="test.3.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test.3.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
           </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data5" id="data5" data-number="4" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data5" >Test 4</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data5" name="data5">
                <option value="test.4.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test.4.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data6" id="data6" data-number="5" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data6" >Test 5</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data6" name="data6">
                <option value="test.5.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test.5.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
           </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data7" id="data7" data-number="6" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data7" >Test 6</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data7" name="data7">
                <option value="test.6.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test.6.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data8" id="data8" data-number="7" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data8" >Test 7</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data8" name="data8">
                <option value="test.7.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test.7.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
           </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" name="data9" id="data9" data-number="8" style="display:none;">
            <label for="data9" >Test 8</label>
           <select type="text" class="form-control" id="data9" name="data9">
                <option value="test.8.1">Evin-1</option> 
                <option value="test 8.2">Evin-2</option> 
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y ya con JavaScript selecciono todos los elementos que tengan data-number y filtro por los que su data-number sean menores o iguales a el valor en numero de tu #cp:

```
function seleccionado(){
    var opt = $('#data1').val();
    
   // alert(opt);
    if(opt=="Perfil-Propio"){
        $('#cp').show(500);
        
    }else if(opt=="Pre-Diseñado"){
            $('#cp').hide();
            $('#data2').hide(500);
            $('#data3').hide(500);
            $('#data4').hide(500);
            $('#data5').hide(500);
            $('#data6').hide(500);
            $('#data7').hide(500);
            $('#data8').hide(500);
            $('#data9').hide(500);
    }
}
    
function seleccionado2(){
    var opt = $('#data1').val();
    var opt2 = $('select#cp').val(); // se le agrega que es un select porque hay 2 ids iguales a #cp
    opt2 = opt2.replace("p",""); // remuevo la p del valor para que quede solo el numero, en el caso de ser 5p queda 5
 
    if(opt=="Perfil-Propio"){
        $("[data-number]").hide(); // oculta todos
        $("[data-number]").filter((index,x)=> x.dataset.number <= opt2).show(500); //filtras todos los  data-numbers que sean menores o igual al numero de seleccionados y los muestras
        
    }else if(opt=="Pre-Diseñado"){
           $("[data-number]").hide(500);
    }
    
}
```

Y sin modificar la funcionalidad que ya habias hecho creo que ya quedaria. Nos dejas sabaer.

Comment: Woww funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias